# Secure Colocation Kiosk

Tags: colocation

I am looking to create a secure colocation kiosk so that customers can confirm http, ping, ssh etc.

This would include just a browser, ssh client (possibly firessh firefox addon), and possibly MTR/traceroute tool.  It would be locked down, and only have said tools available.

Any ideas on how best to accomplish this, or any thoughts on other tools to include for clients?  Would likely be linux-based of course.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A customized live boot linux CD (or usb drive) would seem to be a good answer. These how-to's should point  you in the right direction if you'd like to go down that road.

Knoppix: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7246

Fedora: https://docs.google.com/View?id=ddkxbv6k_7q79q82d7&pli=1

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the tips- I achieved this by modifying Webconverger 8.5 iso and incorporating the ipprotocols firefox extension with a custom file-based homepage.

Comment: please edit your post or comment, but don't post an answer to thanks people.